# Directive link function called twice for same instance

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a directive that performs DOM manipulation. It's link function appears to be called twice, once before the template is well rendered, and once after the template is rendered well enough that the link function can meaningfully use it.

In this instance, it calling the link function twice is actually helpful. Additionally, the call stacks are different (see below), so Angular might have someway to detect if a link function needs to be delayed, though I don't understand how it could without modifying jQuery (as my link function doesn't have any $watches or other Angular methods).

Is there any documentation about this? I want to change the link function in such a way that it won't be idempotent which would be problematic with the current situation (calling it twice would adversely affect a service).

First stacktrace:

```
(anonymous function) (resizable.direc…e.client.js:27)
nodeLinkFn (angular.js:6752)
compositeLinkFn (angular.js:6146)
nodeLinkFn (angular.js:6746)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:6954)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:8171)
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:11768)
$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
done (angular.js:8450)
completeRequest (angular.js:8664)
xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8603)
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:8632)
sendReq (angular.js:8426)
$get.serverRequest (angular.js:8146)
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:11768)
$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
done (angular.js:8450)
completeRequest (angular.js:8664)
xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8603)
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:8632)
sendReq (angular.js:8426)
$get.serverRequest (angular.js:8146)
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:11768)
$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:14426)
completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4411)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:4725)
setTimeout (async)
self.defer (angular.js:4723)
timeout (angular.js:14415)
(anonymous function) (auth.client.service.js:163)
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:11768)
$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
done (angular.js:8450)
completeRequest (angular.js:8664)
xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8603)
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:8632)
sendReq (angular.js:8426)
$get.serverRequest (angular.js:8146)
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:11768)
$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
done (angular.js:8450)
completeRequest (angular.js:8664)
xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8603)
```

Second stack trace

```
(anonymous function) (resizable.direc…e.client.js:27)
nodeLinkFn (angular.js:6752)
compositeLinkFn (angular.js:6146)
nodeLinkFn (angular.js:6746)
delayedNodeLinkFn (angular.js:6974)
compositeLinkFn (angular.js:6146)
publicLinkFn (angular.js:6042)
$get.boundTranscludeFn (angular.js:6166)
controllersBoundTransclude (angular.js:6773)
ngDirective.link (angular.js:21409)
nodeLinkFn (angular.js:6752)
compositeLinkFn (angular.js:6146)
publicLinkFn (angular.js:6042)
$get.boundTranscludeFn (angular.js:6166)
controllersBoundTransclude (angular.js:6773)
ngIfWatchAction (angular.js:19772)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12650)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:14426)
completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4411)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:4725)
setTimeout (async)
self.defer (angular.js:4723)
timeout (angular.js:14415)
(anonymous function) (drive.controller.client.js:98)
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:11768)
$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
done (angular.js:8450)
completeRequest (angular.js:8664)
xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8603)
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:8632)
sendReq (angular.js:8426)
$get.serverRequest (angular.js:8146)
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:11768)
$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
done (angular.js:8450)
completeRequest (angular.js:8664)
xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8603)
XMLHttpRequest.send (async)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:8632)
sendReq (angular.js:8426)
$get.serverRequest (angular.js:8146)
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:11768)
$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:14426)
completeOutstandingRequest (angular.js:4411)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:4725)
setTimeout (async)
self.defer (angular.js:4723)
timeout (angular.js:14415)
(anonymous function) (auth.client.service.js:163)
deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (angular.js:11682)
(anonymous function) (angular.js:11768)
$get.Scope.$eval (angular.js:12811)
$get.Scope.$digest (angular.js:12623)
$get.Scope.$apply (angular.js:12915)
done (angular.js:8450)
completeRequest (angular.js:8664)
xhr.onreadystatechange (angular.js:8603)
```

EDIT: I figured out why the link function is probably called twice. The first time it's called, its element isn't actually in the DOM tree anywhere, as it's a child of an ng-if that is currently false. The second time it's called is when its element is actually inserted into the DOM tree. What is strange is that the DOM element (element[0] in the link function) is different between the calls. I still can't find any documentation for or understand why ngIf compiles its subtree directives if they're not actually in the DOM.

Comment: Do you have any code to show, or how you're implementing your directive?

Comment: do some reading on deeper concepts of angular digest cycles. It's not a one step process. For example put a function instead of an expression for text in html...might see that function called many times even without model being changed

Comment: I have now changed what was previous the link function to the post-link function (which is supposed to be called after the child DOM content has been inserted according to angular). It is still called when ngIf is false; why it calls the post-link function when it is impossible for the child DOM content to be modified (as it doesn't actually exist) is what I don't understand. It still has to call the function again once ngIf evaluates to true.